# How to make IntelliJ IDEA support Java 7 features?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-7

I've started using IntelliJ IDEA recently.

I found a problem: IntelliJ IDEA seems to not support Java 7 features (in fact, I'm trying to use the Diamond Operator).

I changed the settings in the project structure:

[image: project structure]

Then, the red line in IntelliJ IDEA disappeared. But still have a build error:

> 'java: -source 1.6 do not support diamond'

I've finally found a work around: I manually changed the `.idea/misc.xml` file from

```
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_6" 
    assert-keyword="true" jdk-15="true" project-jdk-name="1.7" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
```

to

```
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_7" 
    assert-keyword="true" jdk-15="true" project-jdk-name="1.7" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
```

All works OK. But I still don't know why I must manually change such file.

Am I missing something in IntelliJ IDEA settings?

Comment: You should not have too. If this is reproducible, then you should report it to JetBrains to let them know about the issue.

Comment: Did you restarted IDEA after the change? It usually ask to you to restart to apply the change.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Good idea,it don't ask me and I forget to restart ,too.I'll test it after work.

Comment: @pickypg I'm not sure about the bug I meet.Maybe it occurs with my stupid operations...

Answer (score 0):

As @MarcoAcierno said，I forget to reload the project and idea not remind me .That is the reason.

How to close it ?

Comment: You don't need to "close it". Just accept your own answer ;-)